# Does Meteor Merge Box reuse documents when a subscription changes it's arguments

Tags: meteor, subscription, meteor-publications

If a subscription is rerun with the "same arguments" in a flush cycle it reuses the observer or the server and the data in minimongo:

> If the subscription is run with the same arguments then the “new” subscription discovers the old “marked for destruction” subscription that’s sitting around, with the same data already ready, and simply reuses that. - [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html)

Additionally, if two subscriptions both request the same document Merge Box will ensure the data is not sent multiple times across DDP.

Furthermore, if a subscription is marked for destruction and rerun with **different** arguments the observer cannot be reused, **however my question is:** if there are shared documents being published by the old and new subscription, in the same flush cycle, will the overlapping documents need be intelligently recycled on the client or will they need be sent over the wire a second time.

[Assume there are no other subscriptions that share this data.]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data will be reused I need to double check though.